# Using an aggregate string function with a subquery

Tags: mysql, sql, string, subquery, aggregate

This query selects the following:

```
SELECT jobs.JobID, school.School_Name, 
       CONCAT(staff.First_Name, ' ', staff.Last_Name) AS 'Full_Name', 
       staff.Phone_Number, role.Role
  FROM jobs
 INNER JOIN school ON jobs.SchoolID=school.SchoolID
 INNER JOIN staff ON jobs.StaffID=staff.staffID
 INNER JOIN role ON jobs.roleID=role.roleID
 ORDER BY staff.StaffID asc


JOB ID  FULL NAME   ROLE
------  ---------   ----------
1       BOB         PRINCIPLE
2       BOB         TEACHER
3       JACK        TEACHER
4       SARAH       ACCOUNTANT
5       SARAH       NURSE

ROLE ID    ROLE
------    ----------
1         TEACHER
2         PRINCIPLE
4         ACCOUNTANT
5         NURSE
```

However, I want the results to take only the role with the greatest RoleID:

```
BOB     PRINCIPLE
JACK    TEACHER
SARAH   NURSE
```

I know I can group concatenate this through the following, but what shall I do afterwards?

```
SELECT Full_Name, GROUP_CONCAT(Role) AS Role
  FROM
 (
  SELECT jobs.JobID, school.School_Name, CONCAT(staff.First_Name, ' ', staff.Last_Name) 
     AS Full_Name, staff.Phone_Number, role.Role
    FROM jobs
   INNER JOIN school ON jobs.SchoolID=school.SchoolID
   INNER JOIN staff ON jobs.StaffID=staff.staffID
   INNER JOIN role ON jobs.roleID=role.roleID
   ORDER BY staff.StaffID asc
 ) q
GROUP BY Full_Name
```

From my understanding, I will need to have a sub-query to filter through the strings? Any help is appreciated, thanks.

Comment: What is your logic to keep Nurse for SARAH rather then keeping ACCOUNTANT?

Comment: In this case, there isn't! But I want to later work on a project where a user can have a role in which there are hierarchies. If a user has two different rules, I only want to select the one in the highest heirachy. For now, this is just a simpler example that I thought of.

Comment: Sorry, I am keeping the first role for BOB which has a greater RoleID than teacher (second role)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check this option as well -

```
SELECT
jobs.JobID, 
school.School_Name, 
CONCAT(staff.First_Name, ' ', staff.Last_Name) AS 'Full_Name', 
staff.Phone_Number, 
role.Role
FROM staff
INNER JOIN jobs ON jobs.StaffID=staff.staffID
INNER JOIN school ON jobs.SchoolID=school.SchoolID
INNER JOIN role ON jobs.roleID=role.roleID
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT staff.staffID,MAX(Jobs.roleid) roleid
    FROM Staff INNER JOIN Jobs  ON jobs.StaffID=staff.staffID
    GROUP BY staff.staffID
 ) A ON jobs.StaffID = A.StaffID AND Jobs.roleID = A.roleid
```

Answer (score 1):

use corelated subquery

```
 select a.* from (
    SELECT jobs.JobID, school.School_Name, 
           CONCAT(staff.First_Name, ' ', staff.Last_Name) AS 'Full_Name', 
           staff.Phone_Number, role.Role,staff.staffID,role.roleID
      FROM jobs
     INNER JOIN school ON jobs.SchoolID=school.SchoolID
     INNER JOIN staff ON jobs.StaffID=staff.staffID
     INNER JOIN role ON jobs.roleID=role.roleID
   ) a
 where (a.staffID,a.roleID) in (
      SELECT staff.staffID,MAX(Jobs.roleid) roleID
FROM Staff INNER JOIN Jobs  ON jobs.StaffID=staff.staffID
GROUP BY staff.staffID)
```

or use rownumber() if it is mysql 8.0 or+

```
        select * from
      (
          SELECT jobs.JobID, school.School_Name, 
           CONCAT(staff.First_Name, ' ', staff.Last_Name) AS 'Full_Name', 
           staff.Phone_Number, role.Role,
        row_number()over(partition by role.Role order by jobs.JobID desc) rn
      FROM jobs
     INNER JOIN school ON jobs.SchoolID=school.SchoolID
     INNER JOIN staff ON jobs.StaffID=staff.staffID
     INNER JOIN role ON jobs.roleID=role.roleID
     ) a where a.rn=1
```

Comment: Thank you my friend, the first query does work, but the second query has an error around "row_number()over(partition by role.Role order by jobs.JobID desc) rn"

Comment: @GoGoAllen for 2nd need upper mysql version

Comment: Oops! This is very very close, however I do not want it to group by the role. E.g. if I had another person that had a max role of Teacher, I want to show them too!

Comment: @GoGoAllen as you not mentioned you need to consider staff id as well so i edited my answer